# How do I validate a button in tkinter so that the function is only called once?

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

When I press the 'Enter' button more than once then the text field will keep showing but I want it so that once I have entered my name and pressed the button the button will deactivate. How do I do this?

```
class Enter_Name_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.insert("end", "Please enter your name and class. ")

        enter_name = Entry(self)
        enter_name.pack()

        enter_name.focus_set()

    def callback():
        self.display_name = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.display_name.insert("end", "Now please enter your tutor group.")
        tutor = Entry(self)
        tutor.pack()

        tutor.focus_set()

        Enter_0_2 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback2)
        Enter_0_2.pack()

    def callback2():
        self.display_name = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.display_name.insert("end", "Let's begin! Exit back to main screen.")


    Enter_0 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
    Enter_0.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `state="disabled"` in the Button's `config()` method to disable a widget. You can enable a disabled widget in a similar manner using `state="normal"`.

An example based on your sample code:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.insert("end", "Please enter your name and class. ")

        enter_name = tk.Entry(self)
        enter_name.pack()
        self.enter_0 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=self.callback)
        self.enter_0.pack()

        enter_name.focus_set()
        self.pack()

    def callback(self):
        self.display_name = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.display_name.insert("end", "Now please enter your tutor group.")
        tutor = tk.Entry(self)
        tutor.pack()
        tutor.focus_set()
        self.enter_0.config(state="disabled")

        Enter_0_2 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=self.callback2)
        Enter_0_2.pack()

    def callback2(self):
        self.display_name = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=2)
        self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.display_name.insert("end", "Let's begin! Exit back to main screen.")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: "active" should be used only if the mouse pointer is over the button, otherwise "normal" is the proper state.